# Don't understand export javascript ES6

Tags: javascript, export, ecmascript-6

I don't really understand what does the `export` keyword in ES6. Cause when I do something like the first exemple [here](http://www.exploringjs.com/es6/ch_modules.html), but without export anything in ES5 it's still works.

//------ lib.js ------

```
var sqrt = Math.sqrt;
function square(x) {
    return x * x;
}
function diag(x, y) {
    return sqrt(square(x) + square(y));
}
```

//------ main.js ------

```
console.log(square(11)); // 121
console.log(diag(4, 3)); // 5
```

So of course I know that I miss a big part, that's why I'm looking for some explanation or link that explain what I need to learn cause I don't find anything :)

Comment: `when I do something like above` - there's nothing above!!

Comment: 56 seconds later, google search resulted in http://exploringjs.com/es6/ch_modules.html

Comment: @JaromandaX Like the code in my post. I have updated my post considering your comment, hope it's more clear.

Comment: Did my link help you?

Comment: No because the first exemple used in your link works without using export, so I want to know what is the part I miss, but I already say that in the post

Comment: you miss the import and module parts perhaps

Comment: `export` (and `import`) are used in modules. If you are not using modules then you don't use them.

Comment: I deepened my research, I think I confused a module and a js file called in the script tag.
For a module, it's the javascript file that call the module itself.
So if I well understand, in this : `import * as lib from 'lib';`  lib is a path and never called in a script tag ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ES5 version will certainly work in the browser if you use regular script tags and put first `lib.js` and then `main.js`.

```
<head>
  <script src="./lib.js"></script>
  <script src="./main.js"></script>
</head>
```

**Why does it work on the browser in ES5?**

`function square()` and `function diag()` are global functions and can be accessed from anywhere :(

For example from Chrome dev console.
[image]

**What is different with the ES6 version?**

The `lib.js` functions are not leaking out to the world and are going to be only available to whoever imports them.

For example:

```
import { square, diag } from './lib';
```

This imports the module and then decomposes it and it is only going to have access to `square` and `diag`, but not `sqrt`

As mentioned [here](http://exploringjs.com/es6/ch_modules.html) you could also import the complete lib module.
You can also import the complete module:

```
import * as lib from 'lib';
console.log(lib.square(11)); // 121
console.log(lib.diag(4, 3)); // 5
```

Comment: Thank you ! That answers my question completely, I confused two cases of different uses :)